# Using local storage on a listbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I am working on a history search function.

I have managed to get a working code to save the value from the textbox but I do not know how to load them into a listbox.

I want a listbox with clickable items so that I can click on a previous search value and load that value as I do from the textbox.

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Test</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
      <script src="jquery.js"></script>
      <script src="j.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
    <center>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center">
               <font size="22">S&ouml;k order</font>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <form action="test.php" method="post"> 
                  <input style="font-size: 44pt; text-align: center" size="9" type="text" name="txtSearch" id="txtSearch"/> 
                  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
               </form>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      </center>
   </body>
</html>
```

And the j.js that handles the local storage function.

```
$(function () {

    $("#submit").click(function () {
        var txtSearch = $("#txtSearch").val();
        localStorage.setItem('searchvalue',txtSearch);
    });
});
```

And last my test.php that handles the post search request

```
<?php
$txtSearch = $_REQUEST['txtSearch']; 
header('Location: '.'https://mywebsite.com/se/editor/order_info.php?webshop=23946&ordernr='.$txtSearch);
?>
```

How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: localStorage.getItem('searchvalue')? :)

Answer (score 0):

by js, you can

```
window.location = "https://mywebsite.com/se/editor/order_info.php?webshop=23946&ordernr="+localStorage.getItem('searchvalue');
```

to save in listbox or any other

```
document.getElementById("id").value=localStorage.getItem('searchvalue');
```

to save in array

```
var a = [];
a[0]=localStorage.getItem('searchvalue');
```

Comment: How to fill the listbox with the items? And how do I save em as an array?